# Find folder on network drive, based on username using bash shell in Automator.

Tags: automator

I'm new to Automator, but I've had a Mac for quite some time, and I'm not a total noob. :)

Here is my problem:
Users need to make a backup (to desktop) of a folder located on a network drive. The folder name on the network drive is the same as the user's short username.

This is no problem if the user selects the folder themselves; I´ve made a workflow that does this. But I need this script to automatically find the folder on the network drive, based on the username and copy it to the desktop.

Any ideas how to find that folder and pass it on as my inputfolder variable? I assume I need to use a bash shell or applescript command in my workflow?

Comment: So, you want make an application what when is executed will copy an folder (with name = $USER) from the **known network path** (what is already mounted - e.g. the path is exists in the "/Volumes/something" to the ~/Desktop. right?

Comment: Thats it. I have everything ready, just need the shell command to select the folder (with name = $USER) then pass it on the workflow as a variable (input) the copy is made later in the workflow with: (Get value of variabel (input and output) then get folder contents and finaly copy finder items)

Answer (score 1):

With the information provided, I think the following should work (screenshot follows):

**Run Shell Script**
`echo "afp://192.168.0.115/foto/"`
*Ignore input*

**Get Specified Servers**

**Connect to Servers**

**New Folder**
Name: Backup
*Ignore input*

**Set Value of Variable**
Variable: Destination

**Run Shell Script**
`echo "/Volumes/foto/$USER"`
*Ignore input*

**Copy Finder Items**
To: Destination variable (drag the "Destination" variable from the variable list to the "To" menu)
Check "Replacing existing files" if needed.

#### Variation for Incremental Backups

If you want incremental backups, you could replace **Copy Finder Items** with **New Dated Folder**, also setting its Destination to the Destination variable, and setting the "Action with passed items" option to "Duplicate passed items to the new folder". Make sure to enter something in the "Name" field, otherwise it won't work. To keep the backups listed in chronological order, you can set the Format to be Year-Month-Day and check the following options: "Leading zero for day", "Leading zero month", and "Month as number".

[image: Screenshot of Automator workflow as described above]

Answer (score 0):

Finally you told what you have done. Now need to know what is the result after your `3.Connect to Servers`. Because, the path depends on it.

Check the next screenshot, the connect returns `/Volumes/minidata` and the script add only the `foto` part.

[image: automator screenshot]

Comment: ok, it´s not working. The Shell script works though, and it seems to pass itself on as a variable. But! when i call the variable later in the workflow nothing happens? it does not call the path. maby the path is written wrong? : echo "/afp:192.168.0.115/foto/$USER" I would like to post pictures of my workflow but im not allowed since im new here.

Comment: also tried: echo "afp:192.168.0.115/foto/$USER"

Comment: Even tried a local folder, same thing. The shell script should work just like Get Specified Finder Items.

Comment: as you can see, all actions was passed ok, and got the folder copyed into may Desktop - so, try be more exact FROM WHERE want copy? I already asked you than the PATH IS IN /Volumes. It is in? or you havent a mounted remote fs?

Comment: So you want mount the network drive first?

Comment: here is my work flow: 1.Ask for Confirmation. 2.Get Specified Servers(afp:192.168.0.115/foto)(NAS) 3.Connect to Servers. 4.New Folder(Backup folder on desktop) 5.Run Shell Script(echo "/afp:192.168.0.115/foto/$USER") 6.Set Value of Variable(input) 7.Get Specified Finder Items(Backup folder) 8.Set Value of Variable(Output) 9.Ask for Confirmation(Do you want to copy "input" to "Output"?) 10.Get Value of Variable(input) 11.Get Folder contents(from 10.) 12.Copy folder items(to Backup folder)

Comment: The workflow completed with 2 warnings: "Get folder contents"(11) was not supplied with the required data. and obviesly 12.failes to.... nr.10.does not get the value of the variable!!??

Comment: I will try to shorten the Workflow, not setting any variables, and getting selected finder items, then copy directly from there, like your example.

Comment: finally you told what you have done yet. So what is the result after "3-Connect"?